# How to eliminate Memory Variables when adding two lists with a different length?

Tags: prolog

I am currently trying to calculate the absolute difference of the corresponding elements of two lists.

For this case, I would like the two lists to stop adding values when the length of the first one has run out of values.

Here is an example:

```
?- absDiff([1,3,5,6],[3,5,2,1,2,5],L).
L=[2,2,3,5].
```

I have been trying multiple cases but so far, I have come up with:

```
absDiff([],[],[]).
absDiff([],[_|_],[_|_]).
absDiff([_|_],[],[_|_]).
absDiff([H|T],[H1|T1],[X|L]):-X is abs(H-H1),absDiff(T,T1,L).
```

The returning values I receive when running:

```
?- absDiff([1,3,5,6],[3,5,2,1,2,5],L).
```

is:

```
L = [2, 2, 3, 5, _1334|_1336]
```

I would like to remove the values/variables `_1334|_1336` so the output is simply `[2, 2, 3, 5]`.

How would I go about fixing this? Also, if anyone can explain to me why something like this happens, that would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: At some point, you have `absDiff([],[2,5],L)` and guess what it gives you ?

Comment: `absDiff([],[_|_],[_|_]).` is that true? If you take the difference between the empty list and any non-empty list,  you can get any other arbitrary non-empty list you wish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this:

```
absDiff([],L,L).    % if first list is empty, result is second list
absDiff(L,[],L).    % if second list is empty, result is first list
absDiff([H|T],[H1|T1],[X|L]):-X is abs(H-H1),absDiff(T,T1,L).
```

If one list is empty, you don't even have to try to unify the other list to anything, it just **is** what you want to output.

`absDiff([],[_|_],[_|_]).` doesn't bind the second list with the result, it just says that if the first list is empty and the second **has a head and a tail, regardless what they are**, then the third should have a head and a tail too, but **can be anything**.

---

Note that by doing this, you don't even need the `absDiff([],[],[]).` anymore as it is already contained withing the two other clauses.

---

### Edit

Apologies, I read your code more than I read your explanations, so I assumed you wanted to append the rest of the longest list.
So if you want to cut it instead, all you have to do is:

```
absDiff([],_,[]).    % if first list is empty, result is empty
absDiff(_,[],[]).    % if second list is empty, result is empty
absDiff([H|T],[H1|T1],[X|L]):-X is abs(H-H1),absDiff(T,T1,L).
```